# How to Minimize a NIntegral

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

My problem is to minimize in *Mathematica* a numerical integral. The command

```
FindMinimum[With[{R=2.5},NIntegrate[(R*r1*a)*Sin[r1*a],{r1,1,R}]],a]
```

does calculate the mimimum value of a NIntegral but it returns a message about non-numerical values for sampling points. Possibly a transfer of 'a' into `NIntegrate` is not correct here.
Similarly, the command

```
fun[r1_?NumberQ, R_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ] := (R*r1*a)*Sin[r1*a]
FindMinimum[With[{R=2.5},NIntegrate[fun[r1,R,a],{r1,1,R}]],a]
```

does not work.

I would be grateful for your advice how to couple `Minimize` and `NIntegrate` commands.

Comment: Also note `NMinimize[fun2[2.5, a], a]` will give a better result, albeit more slowly.

Comment: Additionally, your integral is 0 at a=0 -- that is why you get messages.

Comment: You don't need `NIntegrate` at all, `Integrate` provides an analytic result

Comment: Thank you all very very much, the solution by Daniel probably helps. I will check it soon for my real problem where instead of this illustrative function under the integral I have a pretty large expression, i.e. a scalar product for 3-dim quantum well. Thank God that the stackexchange exists.

Comment: I made a community wiki response since this is a common issue and was slightly subtle.

Answer (score 7):

This is a fairly common problem to encounter and in this case was a bit subtle due to having an outer and inner function both in need of being defined only for explicitly numeric input. So I'll repost my comment as an answer and make it a Community wiki.

The `FindMinumum` objective itself needs to be defined only for numeric input. Which can be done as follows for example.

```
fun1[r1_, bigR_, a_?NumberQ] := (bigR*r1*a)*Sin[r1*a]
fun2[bigR_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[fun1[r1, bigR, a], {r1, 1, bigR}]

FindMinimum[fun2[2.5, a], a]

(* Out[49]= {6.74896886521*10^-16, {a -> -7.44151562462*10^-9}} *)
```

One can do better with `NMinimize` although it will be slower to run The above was a split-second).

```
Timing[Minimize[fun2[2.5, a], a]]

(* Out[50]= {3.329455, {-8.91131111427, {a -> -2.46070084014}}} *)
```

Comment: Probably best to edit the extended problem into the original question.

Comment: Great. The application to my problem have revealed one problem more. I need to apply this minimization in loop, like Do[Minimize[...],{bigR,bigRmin,bigRmax}]. The following cases go wrong. Why?
fun1[r1_, bigR_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ] := (bigR*r1*a)*Sin[r1*a]
fun2[bigR_?NumberQ, a_?NumberQ] :=NIntegrate[fun1[r1,bigR,a], {r1,1,bigR}]
(*1*) With[{R = 1}, Minimize[fun2[R, a], a]]
(*2*) Minimize[(fun2[R, a]) /. {R -> 1}, a]
(*3*) abc = 0;
Do[{R = i, abc = abc + Minimize[fun2[R, a], a], Print[abc]}, {i, 
  1}]

Comment: (1) That's a comment, not the original question. (2) It's not formatted very well either; the code cannot be cut-and-pasted. (3) You are using a different minimization function, one that cannot handle these functions. Check documentation for `NMinimize` vs. `Minimize`. Very different animals, those.

Comment: Daniel, allow me to leave the recent extension of the problem as it is because my question is about the generalization of your solution to the cases when bigR is taken from any external procedure.

Comment: Ok, I will work on it. Thank you.