# A complicated use of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am looking for a particular type of plots. OK, let me explain,

Here is my DE (I don't know what to call it),

[image]

where, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} =0$, $r_1=\epsilon$, $r_2=1+\phi\cos(2\pi z)$. 
We have another quantity, $Q(z)=Q^*-(1+\phi^2/2)+\epsilon^2$,

$$Q(z)=2\int_{r1}^{r2}r w[r,z]dr$$,

and finally, we have another quantity,

$$\Delta P=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz$$. The [paper](http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/drs48k16y2722f.pdf), I am reviewing, does this,

1. First solve the original PDE for $w[r,z]$ by treating it as an ODE assuming $p_z$ to be a constant.
2. Integrate $w[r,z]$ w.r.t $r$, then sub the expression for $Q(z)$ and then solve for $p_z$.
3. Finally, integrate $p_z$ w.r.t $z$ to get $\Delta P$.

The authors find analytical solution, which then make the whole process easy but I am looking for a numerical one.

Here is my trying but I am unable to get anywhere with it.

```
r2 = 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]; K1 = 0.2; epsilon = 0.32; phi = 0.4;

sol[P1_, z_] := 
 First@NDSolve[{P1 == 1/r*D[r*D[w[r], r], r] - 1/K1*(w[r] + 1), 
    w[epsilon] == -1, w[1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]] == -1}, 
   w, {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}]

PP1[z_, Q_] := 
 NSolve[(Q - (1 + phi^2/2) + epsilon^2) - 
   2*NIntegrate[
     r*w[r] /. sol[P1, z], {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}], P1]

Plot[PP1[z, 0.1], {z, 0, 1}]



DP[Q_] := NIntegrate[PP1[z, 0.1], {z, 0, 1}]

Plot[DP[Q], {Q, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: I think of `NSolve` as a hybrid symbolic-numeric solver. You probably want `FindRoot` instead.  If I have time later, I'll take a look.

Comment: You should also be careful when calling a minimization inside another minimization for example check this thread : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105948/how-to-minimize-a-nintegral

Comment: Capital `Phi` is undefined and therefore the numeric functions cannot solve equations with symbolic  parameters.  Is it meant to be lowercase `phi`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is `Pi`, sorry about that. But still I am getting errors .

Answer (score 4):

A thorough use of [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) as well as a few other adjustments gives a result:

```
ClearAll[sol, PP1, DP];
r2 = 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]; K1 = 0.2; epsilon = 0.32; phi = 0.4;

mem : sol[P1_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 mem = First@
   NDSolve[{P1 == 1/r*D[r*D[w[r], r], r] - 1/K1*(w[r] + 1), 
     w[epsilon] == -1, w[1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]] == -1}, 
    w, {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}]

PP1[z_?NumericQ, Q_?NumericQ] := Module[{obj, P1},
   obj[P1_?NumericQ] := (Q - (1 + phi^2/2) + epsilon^2) - 
     2*NIntegrate[
       r*w[r] /. sol[P1, z], {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}];
   P1 /. FindRoot[obj[P1], {P1, 1}]
   ];

DP[Q_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[PP1[z, Q], {z, 0, 1}]

Plot[PP1[z, 0.1], {z, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image]

```
Plot[DP[Q], {Q, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
(* takes too long *)
```

Comment: WoW! thanks. Is it possible to make it faster? I mean plotting DP.

Comment: What is this `mem` never saw this before?

Comment: With `Table` I can generate data to plot `DP`. So this problem is solved. Now I am left with another one, how I can plot `w[r]` vs `r`?

Comment: `mem : ...` is a `Pattern` name matching the function call and is used for [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/4999).  It stores the result so that it will not be recomputed.  It's probably not help with speed at all here, because it's unlikely that the functions are being calculated at the same inputs more than once. I forgot it was there or I would have removed it. -- As for other speed-ups, it's unlikely considering how many times `NDSolve` is called.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that the numerical solution coincides with the analytical one, we will find two solutions and compare them. Analytical solution

```
eq = D[r*D[w[r], r], r]/r - (w[r] + 1)/k - pz == 0;
bc = {w[r1] == -1, w[r2] == -1};
sol = DSolve[{eq, bc}, w[r], r];

Q = 2*Integrate[r*w[r] /. First[sol], {r, r1, r2}];

PZ = pz /. 
   First[Solve[Q - Qa + 1 + \[CurlyPhi]^2/2 - \[Epsilon]^2 == 0, pz]];

PZ1 = PZ /. {r1 -> \[Epsilon], r2 -> 1 + \[CurlyPhi]*Cos[2*Pi*z]};

pic1 = Table[
  Plot[Re[PZ1] /. {\[CurlyPhi] -> .4, \[Epsilon] -> .32, k -> K1, 
     Qa -> Q1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"z", "dp/dz"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Grid[{{"\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(Q\), \(_\)]\)=", Q1}, {"K=", 
       K1}}]], {Q1, {0.1, .3}}, {K1, {0.05, .25}}]

pic2 = Table[
  Plot[Re[PZ1] /. {\[CurlyPhi] -> phi, \[Epsilon] -> eps, k -> .1, 
     Qa -> .1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"z", "dp/dz"}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Grid[{{"\[CurlyPhi]=", phi}, {"\[Epsilon]=", 
       eps}}]], {phi, {0.3, .4}}, {eps, {0.38, .42}}]
```

[image: fig1]
Numerical solution has already been obtained by Michael E2, use it and compare two solutions.

```
ClearAll[sol, PP1, DP];
r2 = 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]; K1 = 0.2; epsilon = 0.32; phi = 0.4;

sol[P1_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 First@NDSolve[{P1 == 1/r*D[r*D[w[r], r], r] - 1/K1*(w[r] + 1), 
    w[epsilon] == -1, w[1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]] == -1}, 
   w, {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}]

PP1[z_?NumericQ, Q_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{obj, P1}, 
   obj[P1_?NumericQ] := (Q - (1 + phi^2/2) + epsilon^2) - 
     2*NIntegrate[
       r*w[r] /. sol[P1, z], {r, epsilon, 1 + phi*Cos[2*Pi*z]}];
   P1 /. FindRoot[obj[P1], {P1, 1}]];

DP[Q_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[PP1[z, Q], {z, 0, 1}]

Plot[{PP1[z, 0.1], 
  Re[PZ1] /. {\[CurlyPhi] -> .4, \[Epsilon] -> .32, k -> .2, 
    Qa -> .1}}, {z, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Numerical", "Analytical"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}]
```

[image: fig2]